# using python 3.6 to slice substring with same char

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, slice, python-3.6

I am trying to use python 3.6 to slice string into substring, without importing any module

```
input = "aabbbccaaa"
```

How can i get python to give me:

```
Output = ["aa", "bbb", "cc", "aaa"]
```

---

I am learning python by myself and this is part of the challenge for checkio long repeat, i know i can use itertools module to give the desire output. I just want to know how to do it without using modules.

```
enter code here
def slic(line):
    x= -1
    n=0
    line[x]
    newline=[]
    while x < (len(line)-2):
        x+=1
        n=x+1
        if line[x]==line[n]:
            new= line[x]+line[n]
            newline.append(new)
            print(newline)
```

### slic(aabbbcccd)

output: ['aa', 'bb', 'bb', 'cc', 'cc']

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you show what you've tried even if it has errors as SO isn't a coding service, also it's unclear why you'd need to import a module and did you google string slicing/splitting at all?

Comment: @EdChum probably because what they're asking is easily achieved using itertools or re...

Comment: Wel then either you make your homework yourself, or you pay somebody to do it for you through a code writing service :)

Comment: @JonClements true, but it wasn't clear what they'd tried, other answers they'd seen etc.

Comment: go character by character and if it is same as previous character then you keep it as 1 substring as the character changes you slice it out .. same till the string ends

Comment: But it is not clear why you want to do without importing anything, question is not complete I would say

Comment: I'm sorry but this smells like homework to me. Either do it yourself or be a bit more adept with your googling.

Comment: Hi guys, its not homework, i am learning python and this is for checkio long repeat challenge, i know i can solved it using itertools and regex module, but i am wondering whether is there a way to do it without importing modules. i have tried googling and reading and trying to code it...i only post here as a last resort, hoping the community can help.